# React MaterialUI Clipped Drawer ZIndex Not Working

Tags: reactjs

I have what seems to be a common issue: the "clipped" drawer is overlaying the AppBar component.

I am attempting to use a menu hamburger icon to open the drawer. Opening and closing works fine. The zindex for the AppBar and Drawer components start out at their defaults (1100 and 1200 respectively). Unfortunately, when I click the button, the drawer seems to be created with a zindex of 1300 (copied from devtools):

```
<div role="presentation" class="MuiDrawer-root MuiDrawer-modal makeStyles-drawer-3" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1300; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
<!-- content -->
</div>
```

The actual code is below:

```js
import React from "react";

import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";

import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const drawerWidth = 250;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => {
  console.log(`drawer zindex: ${theme.zIndex.drawer}`);
  console.log(`Appbar zindex: ${theme.zIndex.appBar}`);

  return createStyles({
    root: {
      display: "flex"
    },
    appBar: {
      zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1
    },
    drawer: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0
    },
    drawerPaper: {
      width: drawerWidth
    },
    toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  }
  );

}

);

export default function AppHeader() {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    sidenavOpen: false
  });

  const toggleSidenav = () => {
    const currentlyOpen = state.sidenavOpen;
    setState({...state, sidenavOpen: !currentlyOpen});
  }

  const classes = useStyles();

  console.log(JSON.stringify(classes));
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" onClick={toggleSidenav}>
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h5" >Astronomical Catalog Client (React)</Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <Drawer
                className={classes.drawer}
                open={state.sidenavOpen}
                onClose={toggleSidenav}
                variant="temporary"
                classes={{
                  paper: classes.drawerPaper
                }}
                >
                <div className={classes.toolbar} />


            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is most likely to be a dumb mistake, but if someone can point it out I would greatly appreciate it.